# ModX wayfinder - works on some pages but not on others

Tags: menu, navigation, modx, wayfinder

I have a website where the ModX wayfinder works well on one page, but not on its child pages. The child pages are nested properly in the back end of ModX and everything is displaying with the styles it needs, but when I navigate to the child page in question it it only shows the child page in the menu and the 'Home' button just takes me to the page I am currently on. The parent page that is target is not the home page, but a page from the main menu. The parent and child page both use the same header chunk so I do not believe it to be a typo anywhere else except the wayfinder code. The number next to the parent page is 3439, so I believe thats correct, and I've played around with the &level number and even deleting it entirely, but it is not helping.

So in short - the parent page works beautifully, child pages don't.

Here is my code for the wayfinder. Thank you in advance.

```
[[Wayfinder? 
  &startId=`3439` 
  &level=`1`
  &outerTpl=`wf-outertpl-quick` 
  &innerTpl=`wf-outertpl-quick`
]]
```

Comment: I think you need to increase &level value.
Also, you are using same tpl for "inner" and "outer". This might be an issue.

Comment: Can you post the wf-outertpl-quick chunk? Also 3439 is a high number so I assume the site already has thousands of pages. Do you have the Wayfinder snippet on other pages in the site and is it working on those?

Comment: The wf-outertpl-quick chunk just says [[+wf.wrapper]]

You are correct, there's a whole bunch of pages on this site. We use two different header chunks - one for 95% of the site, and then this one has its own. On the parent page it works, but its the ones below it that don't

Works
example.com/ctl

doesn't work
example.com/ctl/stuff

Both of these use the header-program chunk

And yes Zaigham, it is using the same tpl for inner and outertpl. I'll play around with it in the meantime, thank you